# create array based on number of html elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, dynamic, svelte

My goal is to change the value of activeindex in each of the button elements based on a conditional statement. There are 5 buttons if the flag is true, and there should be 4 when false. However I need to calculate the activeIndexes basedon the condition, instead of them being hardcoded. Example: when the flag is off then the last button should have an activeindex of 3, not 4. I imagine I will loop or create a array but little stuck.

```
let flag = true;
let links = document.getElementsByClassName('link');

<button class='link' activeIndex={0} />
<button class='link' activeIndex={1} />
{#if flag}
<button class='link' activeIndex={2} />
{/if}
<button class='link' activeIndex={3} />
<button class='link' activeIndex={4} />
```

Comment: One question is why you need to use indices in the first place.

Comment: its a larger project (i didnt create it, just involved now). But one method i think might be using for loop and creating an array first.. I would have had it render a list of buttons with .map or somethings personally.

Comment: You also should try to avoid DOM queries like `document.getElementsByClassName` when using Svelte.

Comment: Use a variable that you increment: `activeIndex={i++}`.

Comment: I thought of that @barmar but how do i write that?

Comment: I don't know Svelte, but I'm guessing you just write exactly that, after initializing the variable to `0` at the beginning.

Comment: @Barmar Does not work like that, Svelte is declarative so you should not modify state during its template execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One really dirty fix would be to just add `1` conditionally (do not do this):

```html
{#if flag}
  <button class='link' activeIndex={2} />
{/if}
<button class='link' activeIndex={2 + (flag ? 1 : 0)} />
<button class='link' activeIndex={3 + (flag ? 1 : 0)} />
```

With an array you can do something like:

```html
<script>
    let flag = true;
    
    $: links = [
        { data: 'a', show: true },
        { data: 'b', show: true },
        { data: 'c', show: flag },
        { data: 'd', show: true },
        { data: 'e', show: true },
    ].filter(x => x.show);
</script>

{#each links as link, i (link)}
    <button>
        Button {link.data} Index: {i}
    </button>
{/each}
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/129b446cb3ae43a7ba88e1d180a41607?version=3.49.0)

`{#each}` provides its own index, so you just have to add/remove the respective item to/from the array.

Comment: I will probably go back and change the approach to this problem later but this works for svelty land!